# Shell script - exiting before completion

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have made a short shell script which launches a VM, sleeps some time to allow the VM to boot and then mounts a share at the VM on the host computer:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup VBoxManage startvm "Ubuntu server" --type headless &&
sleep 60 &&
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/www /media/ubuntuserver/
```

The VM is started properly and the script sleeps but **no mount occurs and the script seems to just exit instead**. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your `sudo mount` working in non-interactive mode? make sure this command is not asking any password

Add some logging so that you know what output is being returned

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup VBoxManage startvm "Ubuntu server" --type headless 2>&1 >> ~/script_log.txt &&
sleep 60 2>&1 >> ~/script_log.txt &&
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/www /media/ubuntuserver/ 2>&1 >> ~/script_log.txt
```

replace `~/script_log.txt` with any suitable log file path